# Class App\Repository\AdRepository does not exist

Tags: php, symfony

Do you have any idea on the origin of ReflectionException

for the controller here is the code I wrote

```
public function show($slug, AdRepository $repo)
{
    $ad = $repo->findOneBySlug($slug);
    return $this->render('ad/show.html.twig', ['ad' => $ad]);
}
```

Class App\Repository\AdRepository :

```
<?php

    namespace App\Repository;
    
    use App\Entity\Ad;
    use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
    use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
    
    /**
     * @method Ad|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
     * @method Ad|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
     * @method Ad[]    findAll()
     * @method Ad[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
     */
    class AdRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
    {
        public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
        {
            parent::__construct($registry, Ad::class);
        }
    
    }
```

thank you

Comment: So - __where is__ `AdRepository` class?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I put it now on the post.

Comment: I changed the IDE and its worked. You think that the problem is related to the configuration of the IDE

Comment: Can you show the class itself

Comment: here it is the class AdRepository

Comment: The IDE is not going to impact your Symfony code.  Probably needed to clear the cache though it is hard to say exactly why it started working.  By the way, [avoid using images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) in your questions.

Comment: Ok @Cerad, i also think it's a problem with the cache

Comment: Is this solved? If so, I would vote to close this issue as not reproducable,

Comment: Yes it is solved by restarting the IDE. You can close It. Thanks @dbrumann